# how to include a responsive header with php and css3

Tags: php, css

I am building a personal portfolio webpage as a school assignment for my study Information science at the university of Amsterdam. Right now I copy and paste my header to each new page I make, so I can make little changes which show people at which page they are. Copying and pasting everytime you make a new page is far from efficient. I want to include the header code with a php file. But how can I still make little changes per page then?

My page: http://annatol.nl/

I hope anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance,

Anna

Comment: in this you can add header using include function and the rest of element exists there or not it could not show

Comment: you want to display page name dynamically or you want the same css or header should apply for all the pages?

Comment: Use database to get the page title and content.

Comment: Hello Anna, is learning php part of your studies? If yes then you will probably be expected to use the techniques taught in class. There are many ways to do this, so copying something from SO is unlikely to help you.

Comment: @shridhar dynamically

Comment: @steve yes I have studied php too, but less. The problem is that for this project you're only expected to work with css and html and php if you really really need it, not my choice, but I secretly hoped there would be a short php code to make this possible.

Comment: +1 to @steve - use the techniques taught in class. However, in PHP you will be using the global variables to get information about which page you are on and use this to change the information displayed so it may be worthwhile reading up on these - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php  Once you have understood these you will be able to write your own solution.

Comment: @AnnaTol Well as i said there are many ways to do this. N.Hodin presents one way. Another would be to not include a sperate header at all, but instead run all requests through a single index.php file, and include different page content based on requested page. That would be the very beginning of a front controller as used by the vast majority of modern php frameworks

Answer (score 1):

In your main php script :

```
<?php
include_once('inc/header.php');
?>
```

In your inc/header.php script :

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($page) {
    case "/projects.html":
    //Do specific stuff for Projects page
    break;
    case "/otherpage.html":
    //Do specific stuff for another page
    break;
    default:
    //In other cases...
    break;
}
?>
```

Or if you need inline changes, you can do something like this in your header.php script :

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<a href="/projects.html" <?php if($page == "/projects.html") { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>>My projects</a>
```

Comment: Note that if she intends to use .html file extensions (as indicated in youir switch statement) she would need to configure her web server to run html files through the php interpreter

Comment: You're right, the purpose on my answer is to show her the basic logic to use for her problem, the final answer deserves more search and learning from her side.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
include 'header.php';
```

Comment: I know that. But how can I still make a change per page in the header (like by making the page they're at in the menu another color) to let the user know they're at that specific page. I do that by making the color of the photo in color and the rest in black and white. In the class I give the photo that belongs to the that page a 'none'. But my question is, how can a I combine including a php file with making changes per specific page. I have trouble with putting my question under words, but I hope you understand now.

Comment: Maybe you could create a table only for pages. And for each page you can set values in that table. Then run a query in your included `header.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can include all the files by using the include function

Example:

**include** "Path_To_File";

you can also use the **require** or **require_once** functions aswell